# Java Type-Refinement mapping

Tags: java, polymorphism, automapper, mapstruct, orika

Working with Jackson and Hibernate that both support polymorphism, i would like to find a nice Java mapping library that will help me to separate my different layers (mainly DTO/Entities) and that will also support polymorphism.

Orika seems to support polymorphism (but not without declarations of Types).
https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/

I didn't find good examples for the two other contenders Selma and MapStruct.
http://www.selma-java.org/
http://mapstruct.org/

Have anyone experienced with those libraries ?

Update 1: 
One of the test case.

```
public class PolymorphicMapperTest {

public abstract class Animal{

    private String fooAnimal;

    public Animal(String fooAnimal) {
        this.fooAnimal = fooAnimal;
    }

    public String getFooAnimal() {
        return fooAnimal;
    }
}

public  class Cat extends Animal {

    private String fooCat;

    public Cat(String fooAnimal, String fooCat) {
        super(fooAnimal);
        this.fooCat = fooCat;
    }
}

public  class Snake extends Animal {

    private String fooSnake;

    public Snake(String fooAnimal, String fooSnake) {
        super(fooAnimal);
        this.fooSnake = fooSnake;
    }

    public String getFooSnake() {
        return fooSnake;
    }
}


public abstract class AnimalDTO{
    public String fooAnimal;
}

public  class CatDTO extends AnimalDTO {
    public String fooCat;
}

public  class SnakeDTO extends AnimalDTO {
    public String fooSnake;
}


@Test
public void testMapping() {

        Mapper mapper = MyAwesomeMapper();
        mapper.declare(Animal.class,AnimalDTO.class);

        SnakeDTO snakeDTO = new SnakeDTO();
        snakeDTO.fooAnimal = "Snake";
        snakeDTO.fooSnake = "Anaconda";

        //I don't want the mapper to know the input Type because Jackson will hide it to me.
        AnimalDTO animalDTOToMap = (AnimalDTO) snakeDTO; 


        Animal animal1 = mapper.map(animalDTOToMap);
        Assert.isTrue(animal1 instanceof Snake);
        //And when casted we want to find Animal and Snake fields mapped


        CatDTO catDTO = new CatDTO();
        catDTO.fooAnimal = "Cat";
        catDTO.fooCat = "Persan";

        AnimalDTO secondAnimalDTOToMap = (AnimalDTO) catDTO;

        Animal animal2 = mapper.map(secondAnimalDTOToMap);
        Assert.isTrue(animal2 instanceof Cat);
        //And when casted we want to find Animal and Cat fields mapped


}
```

}

Comment: Can you describe how your mapped hierarchies look like and what kinds of mappings you'd like to achieve. MapStruct definitely supports mapping of types in inheritance hierarchies (mappings include super-type properties etc.), but it'd help to see what issue with polymorphism you actually have in mind.

Comment: @Gunnar Thank you for responding, i updated with a basic test case. The idea here is to not have to write ( and if possible declare) that Snake will be mapped to SnakeDTO but to have introspection figuring it out. What i would like to achieve is that if i have N type of animals to add in the futur and their corresponding DTO i don't have to modify any mapper. Like Jackson(even if i need to declare for this one) or Hibernate will do.

Comment: Typically this is what is described here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/366

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The ticket is open on the MapStruct backlog
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/131